# Session's variable is not save from Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Global.asx and its event `Application_Error` to catch the exception and save it in my session like this :

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception err = Server.GetLastError();
    Session.Add("LastError", err);
}
```

If I look in `Session` right after the `Add`, this exception is saved but when I try to read it from my error page (to handle it and display a warning), `Session["LastError"]` is null.

Did I forget something ?
Thanks for your help.